# Debian apt, gpg keys and constant overwriting of signed-by

Tags: debian, apt, gpg

The `apt-key` has been depreciated. E.g. here they describe how to migrate to gpg keys. Great but it works for a month or so until the `sources.list` file gets overwritten. Why or how it gets overwritten, I have no idea, just that at some point it gets overwritten and I have to do the process again. Typical examples of external repositories that do that: geogebra or google earth. In both cases, the line `deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/geogebra.gpg]  http://www.geogebra.net/linux/ stable main` gets overwritten to:
`deb http://www.geogebra.net/linux/ stable main`.

Anyone else has this experience and a solution to this quite annoying "new feature"?

Comment: Do you have the file `/etc/default/geogebra`? If so can you give its content?

Comment: Btw, such "feature" isn't from Debian, it would be from the package. And anyway I'm quite sure apt-key was done at the same time, so you'd have to also remove the key added (`apt-key del ...`)

Comment: That's definitely not a debian feature. Sounds like some software you've installed is messing with things. and seeing it affects your geogebra repository only, tht would be my primary suspect. But then the question becomes why geogebra even has privileges to do that, being a didactic math tool, and not a system administration tool.

Comment: @Marcus it’s typically done by package maintainer scripts during upgrade, or by a cron job.

Comment: And that's what is doing geogebra: a crontab entry + postinst, but it should not be doing this by default. I suspect it did by default it in the past, but shouldn't do it anymore *by default* (old settings doing it are probably still around for OP).

Comment: @A.B the contents of the `/etc/default/geogebra` are two lines: `repo_add_once="false"`
`repo_reenable_on_distupgrade="true"`

Answer (score 0):

### The package did it

... not Debian.

According to the content of the package *geogebra* (retrievable from this place: `http://www.geogebra.net/linux/pool/main/g/geogebra/`) and its metadata, which can all be extracted for example in `/tmp/geogebra` and examined with:

```
dpkg-deb --raw-extract geogebra_4.2.60.0-30762_all.deb /tmp/geogebra
cd /tmp/geogebra
```

`DEBIAN/postinst` file:

> ```bash
> [...]
> DEFAULTS_FILE=/etc/default/geogebra
>
> ## MAIN ##
> if [ ! -e "$DEFAULTS_FILE" ]; then
>   echo 'repo_add_once="true"' > "$DEFAULTS_FILE"
>   echo 'repo_reenable_on_distupgrade="true"' >> "$DEFAULTS_FILE"
> fi
>
> # Run the cron job immediately to perform repository configuration.
> nohup sh /etc/cron.daily/geogebra > /dev/null 2>&1 &
> ```

This writes the initial `/etc/default/geogebra` as:

```bash
repo_add_once="true"
repo_reenable_on_distupgrade="true"
```

`etc/cron.daily/geogebra` (which is run once a day):

> ```bash
> #!/bin/sh
> [...]
>
> # System-wide package configuration.
> DEFAULTS_FILE="/etc/default/geogebra"
>
> # sources.list setting for GeoGebra updates.
> REPOCONFIG="deb http://www.geogebra.net/linux/ stable main"
>
> [...]
>
> update_bad_sources() {
> [...]
>   # Don't do anything if the file isn't there, since that probably means the
>   # user disabled it.
>   if [ ! -r "$SOURCELIST" ]; then
>     return 0
>   fi
> [...]
>
> # Detect if the repo config was disabled by distro upgrade and enable if
> # necessary.
> handle_distro_upgrade() {
>
> [...]
>
>  SOURCELIST="$APT_SOURCESDIR/geogebra.list"
>  if [ -r "$SOURCELIST" ]; then 
> [...]
>  fi
>
> ## MAIN ##
> DEFAULTS_FILE="/etc/default/geogebra"
> if [ -r "$DEFAULTS_FILE" ]; then
>   . "$DEFAULTS_FILE"
> fi
>
> if [ "$repo_add_once" = "true" ]; then
>   install_key
>   create_sources_lists
>   RES=$?
>   # Sources creation succeeded, so stop trying.
>   if [ $RES -ne 2 ]; then
>     sed -i -e 's/[[:space:]]*repo_add_once=.*/repo_add_once="false"/' "$DEFAULTS_FILE"
>   fi
> else
>   update_bad_sources
> fi
>
> if [ "$repo_reenable_on_distupgrade" = "true" ]; then
>   handle_distro_upgrade
> fi
> ```

which will have changed `/etc/default/geogebra` after first run into:

```bash
repo_add_once="false"
repo_reenable_on_distupgrade="true"
```

This will thus each day or on each upgrade proceed to run functions `update_bad_sources()` and `handle_distro_upgrade()`

which are two places where the package attempts to re-enable its own repository in its own way.

---

### Prevent the package `geogebra` to (re)add its own repository

According to the content, it's possible to avoid this by *not* having at all the file `/etc/apt/sources.d/geogebra`. But there's no guarantee how this will work in the future.

So currently renaming `/etc/apt/sources.d/geogebra` into `/etc/apt/sources.d/local-geogebra` *should* prevent the package to manage its own repository source (except at initial installation).

Optionally one could also in addition create an empty file and make it immutable so the package's content won't be able to change it even if its future behavior changes. As the upgrade script doesn't check such upgrade's return code (`nohup ... &`) it won't even fail during an upgrade.

So:

```
mv /etc/apt/sources.d/geogebra /etc/apt/sources.d/local-geogebra
```

and also optionally:

```
touch /etc/apt/sources.d/geogebra
chattr +i /etc/apt/sources.d/geogebra
```

One other way is to prevent the *crontab* file to be executed by renaming it at the package level into a name that will be ignored by [cron's Debian-specific ignore list](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/cron/cron.8.en.html#DEBIAN_SPECIFIC) (and not found by *postinst*):

> For example, **any file containing dots will be ignored**. This is done to
> prevent cron from running any of the files that are left by the Debian
> package management system when handling files in /etc/cron.d/ as
> configuration files (i.e. files ending in .dpkg-dist, .dpkg-orig,
> .dpkg-old, and .dpkg-new).

So instead or in addition of above:

```
dpkg-divert --local --rename --divert /etc/cron.daily/geogebra.disabled --add /etc/cron.daily/geogebra
```

should prevent, both before or after the package is installed for the first time, to have `/etc/cron.daily/geogebra` executed and the package to attempt to manage its own repository.

The key added with `apt-key` doesn't appear to be automatically re-added after initial setup. If still present, which can be checked with:

```shell
# apt-key list office@geogebra.org
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
pub   rsa2048 2013-03-22 [SC]
      9827 2894 F647 8AA4 434B  41D3 C072 A329 83A7 36CF
uid           [ unknown] International GeoGebra Institute <office@geogebra.org>
```

it can be deleted like this:

```shell
# apt-key del office@geogebra.org
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
OK
```